# Como alterar o filename para download?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, pdf

Estou gerando um arquivo PDF e uso HTML5 para exibi-lo na tela:

```
 $("#conteudo-pdf").append('<object data="' + meuData + '" type="application/pdf" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></object>')
```

O conteúdo é exibido corretamente, e é criado uma barra de ferramentas, onde é possível fazer download do arquivo:

**Firefox:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Chrome:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**IE:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Opera:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao clicar em "Download" a seguinte tela é aberta;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Atualmente, para cada navegador, um nome de arquivo padrão diferente é gerado. Neste caso, o Firefox traz pré-definido como "document.pdf".

Eu gostaria de altera-lo para um um nome de minha preferência que funcionasse em todos os navegadores.

Isso é possível?

Comment: Excelente pergunta. Nem imagino como fazer isso!

Comment: Talvez isso ajude, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717851/save-file-javascript-with-file-name

Comment: @David, no meu caso o problema é que a barra de ferramentas é criada dinamicamente via HTML 5, e cada Browser se comporta de uma maneira diferente, impossibilitando usar dica dada no link que você postou.

Comment: @Sanção é um link.

Answer (score 5):

Se for possível editar a barra de ferramentas teste isto:

```
<a href="download/document.pdf" download="nome_desejado">Download PDF</a>
```

Com base em seu comentário resolvi editar a resposta!

Após analisar uma um pdf aberto no FireFox, notei que ele carregou um js chamado "viewer.js" e olha que interessante função dentro dele:

```
function getPDFFileNameFromURL(url) {
  var reURI = /^(?:([^:]+:)?\/\/[^\/]+)?([^?#]*)(\?[^#]*)?(#.*)?$/;
  //            SCHEME      HOST         1.PATH  2.QUERY   3.REF
  // Pattern to get last matching NAME.pdf
  var reFilename = /[^\/?#=]+\.pdf\b(?!.*\.pdf\b)/i;
  var splitURI = reURI.exec(url);
  var suggestedFilename = reFilename.exec(splitURI[1]) ||
                           reFilename.exec(splitURI[2]) ||
                           reFilename.exec(splitURI[3]);
  if (suggestedFilename) {
    suggestedFilename = suggestedFilename[0];
    if (suggestedFilename.indexOf('%') !== -1) {
      // URL-encoded %2Fpath%2Fto%2Ffile.pdf should be file.pdf
      try {
        suggestedFilename =
          reFilename.exec(decodeURIComponent(suggestedFilename))[0];
      } catch(e) { // Possible (extremely rare) errors:
        // URIError "Malformed URI", e.g. for "%AA.pdf"
        // TypeError "null has no properties", e.g. for "%2F.pdf"
      }
    }
  }
  return suggestedFilename || 'document.pdf';
}
```

Prontinho, agora você já sabe como ele trás o nome padrão "document.pdf".

Comment: Não é possível editar a barra de ferramentas, pois ela é criada dinamicamente via HTML 5, e cada Browser cria de uma forma diferente. Além disso, no caso do Firefox, por exemplo, é criado um `button` e não um `link`. Ainda assim testei o atributo `download`, mas não funcionou.